# android locationManager continues to call onLocationChanged after removeUpdates

Tags: android, gps, location

I've an app that gets a location fix. The app is to be rolled out to phones from Gingerbread up. Once the app gets a location fix a toast message is displayed to the user. The problem is when the user moves to the next activity the toast message appears maybe ten more times.

I think i've implemented the lifecycles correctly eg

1) get a location manager in onCreate()
2) create and pass a location listener to the manager in onResume()
3) remove updates in onStop()

I understand i can bypass this problem in Android > 4.x by calling

```
mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mlocListener, null);
```

but i have to accommodate  Gingerbread so calling a single request is not in api 2.3.x. It works fine on Android 4 but on gingerbread the onLocationChanged method keeps executing another 10 times.

How can i force the onLocationChanged method to run only once on gingerbread?

thanks.

[edit]
I've noticed that when i move to the next activity the onlocationchanged method keeps executing but if i move to a further activity then the location requests are successfully removed

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener); 
    mlocListener = null;
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    if(isCompOptionsReceived == true){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
            mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mlocListener, null);
        }else{
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);   
        }
    }        
    super.onResume();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //toast message
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,                        Bundle extras) {
    }

}//end of MyLocationListener

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
    sIs = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen);
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: this link might help. check the first answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449676/locationmanager-calling-onlocationchanged-too-often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should be executed on the onPause method, not in the onStop

```
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener); 
mlocListener = null;
```

That will fix it for all the android versions.

Comment: Hi, i've amended the code to run in the onPause() method but once a location lock has been aquired, it continues to get about 5 more locks before the listener is removed. This has an effect on my app because in onLocationchanged i present the user with an alert dialog. So you can see a new dialog looping as the location listener is getting new locks before it is finally unregistered. Is there a way to unregister the listener straight away after a lock is found? Thanks

Comment: Of course, you can always unregister the listener the first time onLocationChanged is called ( and ignore further calls ), but it doesn't make much sense to me, specially because the first location is not usually the best one in terms of accuracy and precision

Comment: Hi, i cancelled removed updates within the onLocationChanged method and it works fine. I understand what you are saying with regards to not getting an accurate fix and i wouldn't normally do this where locations are concerned but i only need a lock to call the getTime() on the loc object. It's just to compare external time against system time. Thanks